# How to show a parent view which is outside tableview and is scrollable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a scenario where I need to show a parent view with shadow and corner radius containing a long list of reusable items. I used a tableView to display items. But I stuck at making my tableview expand as much as its contentSize. It works but not accurate. Any solutions?

**Edit:**

Desired result:
[image]

I used the following reference for self sizing tableview.
[Self Sizing UITableView](https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-self-sizing-table-view-2635ac3df8ab)

I made a few modifications as below:

```
final class SelfSizedTableView: UITableView {

    var maxHeight = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let height = min(contentSize.height, maxHeight)
        let size = CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: height)
        return size
    }

}
```

I used a parent tableView with a cell having my containerView and embedding this self sized tableView.

```
class MyContainerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var parentTableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }

    private func estimateDataHeight() -> CGFloat {
        let detailCellHeight: CGFloat = 32
        let headingCellHeight: CGFloat = 43
        let headings: CGFloat = headingCellHeight*2
        let detailsHeight: CGFloat = detailCellHeight*4
        let baseHeight = headings + detailsHeight
        let membersHeight =
            CGFloat(sectionsArray.count) * detailCellHeight
        return baseHeight + membersHeight
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension MyContainerViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let id = String(describing: MyContainerTVCell.self)
        guard let cell = tableView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id, for: indexPath)
            as? MyContainerTVCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
        }

        cell.policyDetails = dataSource
        // my cheat/trick doesn't work on large data.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.4) {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            cell.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.tableView.reloadData() // the overridden one
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension MyContainerViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return estimateDataHeight()
    }
}
```

My cell class which has the self size tableView and containerView:

```
class MyContainerTVCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: SelfSizedTableView!

    // MARK: - Properties
    let titles = ["Email ID:", "Mobile Number:", "Address:", "ID: "] // first section data array
    let moreData: [String] = [] // remaining reusable sections array

    // no of subsequent sections for moreData array type
    var numberOfSections: Int {
        return 4
    }

    // MARK: -
    var dataSource: MyDataSource!

    // MARK: - Life Cycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    // MARK: - Setup
    func setupView() {
        containerView.rounded(with: 10)
        shadowView.layer.applyShadow()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension MyContainerTVCell {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return numberOfSections + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 { return titles.count + 1 }
        else if section == 1 { return moreData.count + 1 }
        else { return moreData.count }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let headerID = String(describing: MyHeaderTVCell.self)
        let itemID = String(describing: MyItemTVCell.self)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                guard let cell = tableView
                    .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerID, for: indexPath)
                    as? MyHeaderTVCell else {
                        return UITableViewCell()
                }
                cell.titleLabel.text = dataSource.title
                return cell
            } else {
                guard let cell = tableView
                    .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: itemID, for: indexPath)
                    as? MyItemTVCell else {
                        return UITableViewCell()
                }
                let item = titles[indexPath.row-1]
                cell.titleLabel.text = item
                cell.separatorView.isHidden = true
                let data: String
                switch indexPath.row {
                case 1:
                    data = dataSource.emailID
                case 2:
                    data = dataSource.mobileNo
                case 3:
                    data = dataSource.address
                case 4:
                    data = dataSource.name
                case 5:
                    data = dataSource.age
                case 6:
                    data = dataSource.id
                case 7:
                    data = dataSource.office
                case 8:
                    data = dataSource.academic
                default: data = String()
                }
                cell.detailLabel.text = data
                return cell
            }

        case 1:
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                guard let cell = tableView
                    .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerID, for: indexPath)
                    as? MyHeaderTVCell else {
                        return UITableViewCell()
                }
                cell.titleLabel.text = "More Data"
                return cell
            } else {
                guard let cell = tableView
                    .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: itemID, for: indexPath)
                    as? MyItemTVCell else {
                        return UITableViewCell()
                }
                let sectionIndex = indexPath.section-1
                guard sectionIndex <= numberOfSections-1,
                    let section = sectionsArray?[indexPath.section-1] else {
                        return UITableViewCell()
                }
                cell.titleLabel.text = moreData[indexPath.row-1]
                cell.separatorView.isHidden = true
                switch indexPath.row {
                case 1:
                    cell.detailLabel.text = section.a
                case 2:
                    cell.detailLabel.text = section.b
                case 3:
                    cell.detailLabel.text = "\(section.c ?? 0)"
                case 4:
                    cell.detailLabel.text = section.d
                case 5:
                    cell.detailLabel.text = section.e
                case 6:
                    cell.detailLabel.text = section.f
                    if indexPath.section < numberOfSections {
                        cell.separatorView.isHidden = false
                    }
                default: break
                }
                return cell
            }
        default:
            guard let cell = tableView
                .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: itemID, for: indexPath)
                as? MyItemTVCell else {
                    return UITableViewCell()
            }
            let sectionIndex = indexPath.section-1
            guard sectionIndex <= numberOfSections-1,
                let section = sectionsArray?[indexPath.section-1] else {
                    return UITableViewCell()
            }
            cell.titleLabel.text = moreData[indexPath.row]
            cell.separatorView.isHidden = true
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.detailLabel.text = section.a
            case 1:
                cell.detailLabel.text = section.b
            case 2:
                cell.detailLabel.text = "\(section.c ?? 0)"
            case 3:
                cell.detailLabel.text = section.d
            case 4:
                cell.detailLabel.text = section.e
            case 5:
                cell.detailLabel.text = section.f
                if indexPath.section < numberOfSections {
                    cell.separatorView.isHidden = false
                }
            default: break
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
extension MyContainerTVCell {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 { return 43 }
        if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 { return 43 }
        return 32
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any screenshots to share?

Comment: Please show code. What have you tried? I can't see why objective-c and swift are tags here because there is no code in your question.

Comment: @Glenn I've added details in the edit. Please ask if any doubt in understanding code or expected result.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I've added code and edited the tags. Please review and ask if any doubt.

Comment: Is it a right approach or any other solution?

Comment: Okay, so, I have no time yet to read thoroughly your code, but I think I get your current approach. Yours is the same with mine. I compute the contents of the tableView inside a tableViewCell to get the height. However, my each height of the rows of the contents is static, say height 50.0, I haven't think about any other way than this.This Friday, I'll check again your thread to see if anyone has a better way. :) and to have an experiment to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to expand `tableView` as much as its content size to make it scrollable, when `tableView` is already scrollable?

However, if you have some other content, aside from table, on the screen and you want them to scroll together, then you need to embed all your content into `UIScrollView`.

Then, make a height constraint for you `tableView` in xib/storyboard with any value.
Then you might do something like this:

```
// in your view controller
private var heightObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

// called once, for example, in viewDidLoad()
private func setupTableView() {
    ...

    observation = tableView.constraintFrameHeightToContentSizeHeight()
}

extension UITableView {

    func constraintFrameHeightToContentSizeHeight() -> NSKeyValueObservation {
        return observe(\.contentSize, changeHandler: { (tableView, _) in
            tableView.heightConstraint?.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
        })
    }
}

// find height constraint
extension UIView {

    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return constraints.first(where: { $0.firstAttribute == .height })
    }
}
```

Don't forget to uncheck "Scrolling Enabled" in xib/storyboard for that table view.